# The Events Calendar Plugin - List View Background Colour Issue

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, css

I'm trying to look for some help, I've got a WordPress website that I'm working on.

I'm using this plugin called **The Events Calendar**, but in List View, the background keeps showing in transparency...

Would somebody be able to help me trigger and find where in the code I can change the background color instead of having it in transparency?

Here is the link: http://bit.ly/1cJlC8e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can add this code to #tribe-events-content.tribe-events-list in your stylesheet like so:

```
#tribe-events-content.tribe-events-list {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    background: #FFFFFF; /* ADD A BACKGROUND COLOR HERE */
}
```

That will add a background to the Upcoming Events section so that the text is more easily readable.

[Here's a screenshot of the change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El7M8.jpg)

Comment: Per [a tri.be tutorial](http://tri.be/what-are-template-overrides-and-how-do-i-do-them/), you can override the CSS using a file in your theme's directory:  `[theme]/tribe-events/events.css`. That way, if you switch themes, you can easily port your CSS overrides (and any other customizations -- read the linked tutorial for more details) to your new theme.